# Add members to google groups programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to take e-mail addresses from a spreadsheet and add them to a Google Group on a "Google Sites" page, as a method for controlling access.  Is there a way to do so from the spreadsheet?  I've seen the provisioning stuff for it at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#adding_a_member_to_a_group but have no idea how to utilize it through the scripting attached to spreadsheets in Google Docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a very basic tool to add users to groups from a spreadsheet.  You have to use column 1 for group Name, column 2 for users emails and let column 3 free to write a yes / no value. Note that the provisioning API is now deprecated and it would be a better idea to go directly to the new [Admin SDK directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) but in the meantime this is still working if the provisioning API is activated in the google apps admin panel.

```
function setGroupFromSS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var dataRange = sh.getRange(2, 1,sh.getLastRow()-1, 3)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var group = row[0];         // 1st col
    var emailAddress = row[1];  // 2nd col
    var done = row[2];          // 3th col
    if (group==""){break};
    if(done==''){
      Logger.log(i+'  '+group+'  '+emailAddress);   
//      var group = GroupsManager.getGroup(group).addMember(emailAddress);// uncomment when your SS setup is ok     
      data[i][2]='yes';
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);// update SS with "done" values
}
```

Comment: That's excellent, I was wanting to avoid the Admin SDK because it seems to force use of OAuth, and I'd be adding people asynchronously from their submissions, so it's a bit of a sticking point.  I'm off to try this now.

Comment: I can't get to apps control panel anymore, assuming I left it unused so my old free 'grandfathered' account has died, do you think you could explain the Admin SDK Method?