# Add members to google groups with the First Names and Surnames or Display Names addess

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-api

I want to add Email Addresses to Google Groups programmatically.  While there are methods of doing so, none seem to allow the addition of the Display Names, Nicknames or just the First and Last names.

For example, the code (from [Add members to google groups programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915390/add-members-to-google-groups-programatically)):

```
 GroupsManager.getGroup(group).addMember(emailAddress);
```

works beautifully if the emailAddress is something like fred@example.com, however if I try to add the DisplayName, it doesn't.  I have tried:

```
 "Fred Surname" <fred@example.com>
```

and
     Fred Surname

however, I just receive an unspecified error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - in any language, as long as there is an example!

Many thanks,

Clem Clarke

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done unless the person is defined as a Google User in the Domain. See this discussion: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/6Z8OpwGk7UM; specifically, the post by marcus24 on 10/10/09. It still works the same way today.

Answer (score 0):

It only works if you add a user with a Google account (includes other Gsuite enabled organisations and Gmail addresses too). It does not works for users with other accounts (e.g Hotmail, iCloud, Yahoo etc).

Hopefully Google will enable GSuite admins to include the person's name with their email address for third party accounts soon.

Answer (score 0):

This format for adding Display names does not work in the New Google Groups.  No matter what format I enter, it puts the email name in the Display Name Field instead of the name that I use to maintain the group, i.e. First Name Last Name.  Since some emails are not remotely associated with a person's name, this is very difficult to manage.  The special input formula works fine in Classic Google Groups but not in the New Google Groups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm admin for a Google for Nonprofits workspace. When adding members to a google group (in the form "First Last <emailaddress.domain>"), the Display Name "takes" only for those users who have accounts in our organizational domain. For the others, the email address is just repeated where I wish the Display Name would appear.

Answer (score -1):

It can totally be done, I just did it and have done it before.  When adding a new member to the group type the name as you want it displayed then the address in the `<>`'s.  Ex. `John Doe <email address>`
Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't work for domains outside the google app domain.